# Shopware 6 Update Error "Incorrect combination of licensing host and Shopware Acc

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

Recently i'm running in an issue while try updating Shopware 6.4.

I can't update any plugins nor shhopware itself. When Running Update routine via backend spinner keeps running endlessly. in browser network tab i can see that there was a request made via `/api/_action/update/check-requirements` resulting in status 500.

Further investigation into response showed that following error detail:

"Client error: 'GET [https://api.shopware.com/swplatform/autoupdate/permission?shopwareVersion=6.4.3.0&language=en-GB&domain=my.domain'](https://api.shopware.com/swplatform/autoupdate/permission?shopwareVersion=6.4.3.0&language=en-GB&domain=my.domain%27) resulted in a '401 Unauthorized' response:\n{"success":false,"code":"ShopwarePlatformException-22","title":"Incorrect combination of licensing host and Shopware Acc (truncated...)\n"

I checked if `my.domain` is setup in Shopware instances backend: license configuration as well as corresponding entry in Shopware accounts shop-domains and if they match. So that can't be the problem hopefully. Even in `.env` domain matches to `my.domain`.

Can anybody help and suggest what else could be the problem?

Thanks

I tried everything i could.

Comment: Did you try to login again with the Shopware admin panel to your Shopware account?

Comment: Yes I tried, but with no difference. But fortunately i found an old backup. On comparison i figured out that some of the `core.store` values in `system_config` table changed. Although i couldn't figure out the reason for that. Luckily replacing that values with those of backup solved that issue on my case. For once the shopware Secret in db was wrong, as well as was another id. Very tricky indeed.